# Wordpress WooCommerce - Get Attributes Options Names

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce on Wordpress, my question is how do I get the attributes option names? I have this code here:

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ):
    $attribute_data = $attribute->get_data();
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($attribute_data); echo '</pre>'; 
    break; 
endforeach;
```

which gives me the attributes with the options, but not the option names, it appears as its giving me the option id?

How do I get the option name of an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
foreach( $attributes as $att ):
    $options = $att->get_terms();

    foreach( $options as $option) {
        echo $option->name;
    }
 endforeach;
```